# How to detect when the form is being maximized?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, event-handling, delphi-xe2

I would like to detect when the form is going to be maximized to save certain settings (not related to the size nor position) and modify the size and position a little bit. Is there an universal way to do it ?
I've tried to catch the WM_SYSCOMMAND message like in [this article](http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2007/qt/sc_restore.htm). It works well for maximization from menu, by maximize button, but it's not fired when I press the WIN + UP keystroke. Does anyone know an universal way how to catch the maximization event including the case with WIN + UP keystroke ?

Thanks

Comment: you can handle the `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`.

Comment: @kobik, thanks, but the size and position is not the only things I want to do (bad example, I know). I really need to detect when the window is going to be maximized and I can't recognize it in WM_GETMINMAXINFO.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [`WM_GETMINMAXINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632626%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to save the state of the window and then use the [`WMSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632646%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to check if the window was maximized.

in you form declare the mesage handler like so :

```
procedure WMSize(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_SIZE;
```

And handle like this :

```
procedure TForm57.WMSize(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  if Msg.WParam  = SIZE_MAXIMIZED then
    ShowMessage('Maximized');    
end;
```

Comment: Wont this fire too late? (*after* the form is maximized).

Comment: @kobik, Yes this message fires after of maximize, the OP can use `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` to save the state and then use `WMSize` to check if the window was maximized.

Answer (score 7):

WIN+UP does not generate `WM_SYSCOMMAND` messages, that is why you cannot catch them.  It does generate `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`, `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`, `WM_NCCALCSIZE`, `WM_MOVE`, `WM_SIZE`, and `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` messages, though.  Like RRUZ said, use `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` to detect when a maximize operation is about to begin and `WM_SIZE` to detect when it is finished.

Answer (score 7):

IMO, You cannot use `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` to "detect when a maximize operation is ***about to begin***" as @Remy stated.

In-fact the only message that can is `WM_SYSCOMMAND` with `Msg.CmdType=SC_MAXIMIZE` or undocumented `SC_MAXIMIZE2 = $F032` - but it's not being sent via `Win+UP`, or by using `ShowWindow(Handle, SW_MAXIMIZE)` for example.

The only way I could detect that a window is about to be maximized is via `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` which is fired right after `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    procedure WMWindowPosChanging(var Message: TWMWindowPosChanging); message WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING;
  end;

implementation

const
  SWP_STATECHANGED = $8000;

procedure TForm1.WMWindowPosChanging(var Message: TWMWindowPosChanging);
begin
  inherited;
  if (Message.WindowPos^.flags and (SWP_STATECHANGED or SWP_FRAMECHANGED)) <> 0 then
  begin
    if (Message.WindowPos^.x < 0) and (Message.WindowPos^.y < 0) then
      ShowMessage('Window state is about to change to MAXIMIZED');
  end;
end;
```