# Detect all situations where form is minimized

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe2

I need to detect when a form is minimized (to hide overlay form). I intercept `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message and it works fine if I click the form's minimize button, but this event seems not to be fired if I use [Windows] + [M]. Also, `WM_ACTIVATE` and `WM_ACTIVATEAPP` are not triggered in this case.

What event could I use and are there any other situations that I would have to detect?

Comment: Hooking WM_SIZE will not work as expected without  `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;` in the project (AFAIK introduced with D 2007). You might use `Application.OnMinimize` or encapsulated ApplicationEvents.OnMinimize to detect the minimizing of the mainform in such cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained here, [`How to detect when the form is being maximized?`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9704075/576719), listen to the `WM_SIZE` messages.

Declare in your form:

```
procedure WMSize(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_SIZE;
```

And implementation:

```
procedure TForm1.WMSize(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  Inherited;
  if Msg.WParam  = SIZE_MINIMIZED then
    ShowMessage('Minimized');
end;
```

**Update**

See also the answer by [`@bummi`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20200336/576719) where there is a solution when `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar = false`.

Comment: Don't forget `inherited;`.

Comment: Any ideas as to when this does not work? It works on a new VCL form but in my actual main form I do not get any WM_SIZE when minimizing :(

Comment: I don't see why you talk about WM_GETMINMAXINFO

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yes that was irrelevant here, removed.

Comment: @jpfollenius, is the message being stopped to propagate somewhere in your code?

Comment: That's better but I still don't understand the relevance of the answer you link to.

Comment: That is clear in my opinion, detecting maximize or minimize is similar, and the problem was the same, how to detect when user pressed [Window] + [Special Key], not only when using the windows minimize/maximize buttons.

Comment: Accepted. Maybe we can add the hint @bummi provided about `Application.MainFormOnTaskBar`?

Answer (score 6):

Since WM_SIZE will not be called on a mainform of a project not using the setting `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;`  I'd suggest an approach, inspired by inspired by @kobik 's answer on [, How to detect when the form is being maximized?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9707650/1699210).

WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING will be called independed from MainFormOnTaskbar with different signatures on Message.WindowPos^.flags and respond on <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> too.

```
procedure TForm3.WMWindowPosChanging(var Message: TWMWindowPosChanging);
const
  Hide1=(SWP_NOCOPYBITS or SWP_SHOWWINDOW or SWP_FRAMECHANGED or SWP_NOACTIVATE);
  Hide2=((SWP_HIDEWINDOW or SWP_NOACTIVATE or SWP_NOZORDER or SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSIZE));
begin
  inherited;
  if ((Message.WindowPos^.flags AND Hide1)  = Hide1)
         or ((Message.WindowPos^.flags AND Hide2)  = Hide2)  then
  begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Window got minimized');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: +1 thank you very much! That was exactly the problem ('Application.MainFormOnTaskbar` being not set). I will accept the other answer though as it answers the question itself better.

Answer (score 2):

Listen for [WM_SIZE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632646.aspx) notification messages with a wParam parameter of SIZE_MINIMIZED.

Comment: Any ideas as to when this does not work? It works on a new VCL form but in my actual main form I do not get any WM_SIZE when minimizing :(

Comment: What's different about your form?

Comment: I can't see any difference. I will have to investigate this. So far, +1 for both answers.

Comment: Override WndProc in your main form and see if the message arrives there. Is it even delivered?

Comment: `WM_SIZE` is generated by `DefWindowProc` when it handles `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` or `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` (I don't remember which, but I believe it's the second one). If the `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` message is not forwarded to DefWindowProc, then you will not get a `WM_SIZE` message.